# Using die() in functions under CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm writing a web application in CodeIgniter and I'm trying to apply user activation.

```
    function is_active() {
        $active_state = $this->my_model->check_active();
        if ($active_state == 'no') {
            $this->load->view('activation_page');
            die();
        }
    }
```

above code will produce a blank page and if I remove die(); if will print out members_area alongside with activation_page

so How can I force this to load the requested view and exit?

Comment: you dont need to use die() at all

Comment: Thanks, but that way it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you are not going inside the if statement, meaning if the user is NOT active, you load the activation page.

Still you don't have an else, which will load a view if  the user IS active.

Try:

```
 if ($active_state == 'no') {
    $this->load->view('activation_page');
 } 
 $this->load->view('members_area');
```

Note: you might want to revert the if condition. Looks more logical to check if user is active, otherwise fallback to activation page.

**EDIT:**

Please refer to this code: http://paste.laravel.com/pfO

Note 2: One of many possible solutions.

Comment: Actually it does go inside if statement because if I modify it to die('error message'); it will produce the error message from die() inside my if statement. the problem is it doesn't load the view sooner. Thanks

Comment: Where are you using this function is_active()?

Comment: In my controller under __construct

Comment: Make the function is_active return true or false, and then load the view in the next method after the constructor...then it will work.

Comment: Thanks, I made the function return true or false but I didn't understand how to load the view in the next method after construction. what do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 if ($active_state == 'no') {
    $this->load->view('activation_page');
    return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should have played with if condition properly

```
if ($active_state == 'no') {
    $this->load->view('activation_page');
}else{
    $this->load->view('members_area');
}
```

Comment: I did exactly as you said but it still loads two views. Thanks

Comment: @Zim3r you may be loading the other view somewhere else where you are calling `is_active`

Comment: Yes by default it should go to other view but I'm using this under __construct and I think it should do what is stated under __construct first.

Answer (score 0):

I would put your if statement into the controller of your modules instead of in the model.
There you should do the check, as then you can make the if statement around the other view calls. So that it doesn't load the other views which you don't want un-activated users to see.